# How to manipulate css property on ONE class but for multiple instances

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have a parent div with class 'options'.
Inside this parent div, I have 3 more divs with a class 'text'.

My objective to manipulate the 3 child divs (class='text') differently. For example, the first One</> must have font-size of 12px and second instance must have font-size of 21px, etc.

This is how my HTML code looks like:

```
<div className='options'>
   <div className='text'>One</div>
   <div className='text'>Two</div>
   <div className='text'>Three</div>
</div>
```

This is how my current CSS code looks like - and it doesn't work.

```
.options > .text:first-child {
    font-size: 12px !important;
 }
.options > .text:nth-child(2) {
    font-size: 21px !important;
 }
.options > .text:nth-child(3) {
    font-size: 26px !important;
 }
```

Comment: I don't see how your code can't work. Do you have other elements lying inbetween those `.text`?

Comment: Yeah it is odd. It should work. This literally how the struture is of my code. I am not using the 'text' class anywhere else, nor am I changing the 'text' class in my css code elsewhere. The code I provided is all I have.

Comment: How are you importing the CSS into your app?

Comment: It seems to be working, there must be something else causing your problem: https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-dust-xye64h

Comment: Are you sure that there are no more components being added/inserted within the `.options` element?

Comment: Have you used  your browser's devtools inspect facility to absolutely assure yourself that the HTML is exactly as you think it is and that there is no other CSS involved?